# Double tap in webOS

Tags: webos, palm, mojo-sdk

How can I implement DoubleTap event and SingleTap event separately in webOS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your handler for Mojo.Event.tap, look at the event's count field.  That will be 2 for a double-tap, 1 for a single-tap.  Note that you'll always get the single tap first, so make sure you don't do anything destructive on that.